Change only certain text within a table to a different color
I am looking to only change a certain character within each row to a different color. For example, if you look at the attached photo you will see the text in red. I only want what is in (#) to turn red, so the (1), (2), (3) and so on.
I have use the Switch dax, but it colors the entire text as expected. I am stuck and am not sure what else to add to make it work or if it is even possible.
Notes Conditional Color = SWITCH('Current Qtr Target'[If Notes then Y], "y", "Red")


Missing image in your question. Currently you cannot have different colour or formatting with a cell value.

Why was it approved with such glaring deficiencies? There isn't even a question in there.

@PeterMortensen teh picture was not uploaded for some reason - otherwise my question is very clear.

you can try this
Measure = 
var _value=SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[ID])
return SWITCH(_value,"a","Red","b","Blue")

and apply the measure to the font color



Hi, thanks so much but this doesnt do it since the (1) , (2), etc are part of a sentence. what i want is for it to pick rows that contain these texts (1) , (2), etc, and only color the (1) , (2), etc in red. I added a picture for clarity

then you can try this
Measure = if(CONTAINSSTRING(max('Table'[description]),"(*)"),1,0)

then apply the rule to the description column




Thank you. but this does teh same exact thing. i only want the (1) to be red not the a

sry,I misunderstood it. I don't think you can highlight a part of the sentence. it can only highlight the whole cell.
